# How to Compare and fetch the Json records having same Name in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a json with n number of objects I have to fetch "id" attribute from last two objects. Also I have to first compare Id attribute as per the latest added objects to json. Say Id 16941 is to be fetched first and then id 16940 has to be fetched second.

[
     "id" : 16940,
     "version" : 0,
     "direction" : "B",
     }, {
     "id" : 16941,
     "version" : 0,
     "direction" : "S",
     } ]

Comment: Isn't this the same as reading the last two elements from an array?

Comment: If you use String to store JSON parse it to some JsonNode or etc. after that read last two items using ```node.size()-1``` or ```node.size()-2```